# PHP, HTML: Bootstrap for validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form on my website, in which I want to submit some data and search a database. The form has a input field, a drop-down menu and a submit button. I want the input field and drop-down to flag/ not submit if the submit button is pressed and nothing is entered. I have looked here: [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

but it has not worked for me. **When i click submit, it just submits the data eg. nothing, to the next page.**

Here is my form:

```
<header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Enter a username and choose a category to search in</h2>
          <form action="search.php" method="get" novalidate="novalidate" data-toggle="validator" role="form ">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search a username here" required></input>
                    </div>
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cataegory <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu choice">
                          <li value="one"><a href="#">Minecraft username</a></li>
                          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                          <li value="two"><a href="#">Minecraft UUID</a></li>
                          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                          <li value="three"><a href="#">McMarket Username</a></li>
                          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                          <li value="four"><a href="#">Skype Username</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type='hidden' name='choice'>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I have tried many of the solutions posed by members on other threads on this forum, and they haven't worked, so I believe the problem is probably a syntax error. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Are you clear about your requirements? As I see your markup is completely different than http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: Try removing novalidate="novalidate" from your form.

Comment: what is the novalidate="novalidate" in form's start tag?!

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you know how i would get it so that when they choose from the menu, it has the same validation?

Answer (score 0):

Removing novalidate="novalidate" from the form